# Why does this function never return? Is it a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
int position_of_largest(int * array, int size)
{
  int largest, i, largest_i;
  i = 0;
  largest_i = 0;
  while (i < size)
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      largest = array[0];
      largest_i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      if (largest < array[i])
      {
        largest_i = i;
        largest = array[i];
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  return largest_i;
}
```

This code is supposed to find the index of the highest element in the array and return it. 
There is a segmentation fault in this code, apparently, but I have no clue what it is! I have looked through the code many times and I don't see any problem. I am new to C, btw (which explains a lot).  Thanks.

Comment: segmentation fault is when you try to access un-allocated or un-authorized memory space..
i hope when you are calling the function `position_of_largest(int * array, int size)` you are sending a pointer to enough memory space ( size*4 bytes) to the `array` pointer

Comment: Can we see the call of the function? Also, `i++` never gets executed.

Comment: @haris: Sometimes. When you are on the right kind of machine and are unreasonably lucky.

Comment: @Deduplicator what about unfortunately lucky?

Comment: Regarding what a segmentation fault is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/694576

Answer (score 3):

It is not causing segmentation fault but this code goes to an infinite loop. It is because you place `i++` in `else` block. It is never get incremented.

Place it outside the `else` block.

```
else { 
    if (largest < array[i]) {
        largest_i = i;
        largest = array[i];
    } 
}
i++;
```

Comment: @lisacarlisle haccks can laugh too if you "accept" the answer!